# How do I get the duration of all videos in the JWPlayer Playlist?

Tags: html, jwplayer, playlist

I can get the duration of the currently playing item but not of the other items in the playlist. 
I've already tried this:

```
var totalTime = 0;    
var list = new Array();
list = jwplayer().getPlaylist();
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
   totalTime += jwplayer().getPlaylistItem(i).duration;
}
```

BUT i keep getting a return of either NAN or -1, this is not a live stream as the JWPlayer API reference would indicate by a return of -1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm about to just hard-code in the video lengths and call it a day.
- Nick

Comment: There is a post in the forum discussing the same problem, maybe it helps you: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/28026/get-video-duration/

Comment: I would indeed look at that post, it has very useful information.